# Bounds on a prime exponent problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, products, totient-function

In an IMO SL problem for 2020 number theory problem 6, there is a part of the solution which I do not get which states the following:

Let $m>5$ be  large positive integer and also let $n=p_1p_2...p_{\pi(m)}$ be the product of all primes not exceeding $m$. Then $\phi (d(n))=\phi (2^{\pi(m)})=2^{\pi(m)-1}$. Consider the following:

$$\phi(n)=\prod_{k=1}^{\pi(m)}(p_k-1)=\prod_{s=1}^{\pi(m/2)}q_s^{\alpha_s}$$

where $q_1q_2...q_{\pi(m/2)}$ are primes not exceeding $m/2$. Note that every term $p_k-1$ contributes at most one prime $q_s>\sqrt{m}$ in the product $\prod_{s=1}^{\pi(m/2)}q_s^{\alpha_s}$. Hence we have:

$$\sum_{s: \space q_s>\sqrt{m}}\alpha_s \le \pi(m) \rightarrow \sum_{s: \space q_s>\sqrt{m}}(1+\alpha_s) \le \pi(m)+\pi(m/2)$$

**My question:**

1. How do we know that the prime cannot exceed $\sqrt{m}$ ?
2. How can we just state that $\phi(n)=\prod_{k=1}^{\pi(m)}(p_k-1)=\prod_{s=1}^{\pi(m/2)}q_s^{\alpha_s}$, I do not understand the motivation behind the second product of primes $q_{s}$ and its bound on the product of $\pi(m/2)$.
3. In the last inequality how does $\sum_{s: \space q_s>\sqrt{m}}\alpha_s \le \pi(m)$ lead to $\sum_{s: \space q_s>\sqrt{m}}(1+\alpha_s) \le \pi(m)+\pi(m/2)$ ?

I want to understand the remaining of the solution but am stuck on these parts, could anyone kindly explain how those hold true ?

Comment: 1. is, I’m afraid, not clear. 2. this is an IMO SL N6… Motivation at this point is really hard to define. The problem wouldn’t be so difficult if its steps were easy to motivate. But you have a big product, so it’s not too unnatural to consider its prime factorization. Every $q_s$ is at most $m/2$ because every $p_k-1$ is equal to one, or even. For 3., the index $s$ lives between $1$ and $\pi(m/2)$…

Comment: I am really wondering why $q_s$ has to be larger than $\sqrt{m}$....

Comment: Not all $q_s$ do! It’s just that for every $p_k-1$, there is at most one index $s=s(k)$ such that $q_s \mid p_k-1$ and $q_s \geq \sqrt{m}$.